# c++ binary tree help w/template

Tags: c++, struct, binary-tree, return-type

I'm trying to create a binary tree class on c++ and have thus far succeeded at the insert and tree destruction methods. However, I'm stuck and, honestly, completely lost on the search function.

Specifically it's not the algorithm that confuses me but the syntax when trying to return a nested struct of the class.

```
template<typename T>
class BinaryTree{
    struct TreeNode{
        T item;
        TreeNode *leftNode;
        TreeNode *rightNode;
    };
public:


    BinaryTree();
    ~BinaryTree();

    void insert(T x);
    void remove(T x);
    TreeNode *search(T x);

private:
    TreeNode *mainNode;
    void insert(T x, TreeNode *node);
    void destroyTree(TreeNode *x);
    TreeNode *search(T x, TreeNode *node);
};


//return pointer to seached object
template <typename T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode BinaryTree<T>::*search(T x){
return search(x, mainNode);
}

template <typename T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode BinaryTree<T>::*search(T x, BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode *node){
    /* problem here */
    return NULL;
}
```

I can't seem to be able to set set the type of the *node in the parameter of my *search method. Initially, I was stuck on the return type but found the solution by using typename and the resolution operator on the return type. (ie typename BinaryTree::) If I am wrong, i would really appreciate some guidance.

Comment: So, what's the error you're getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That would be:

```
template <typename T>
typename BinaryTree<T>::TreeNode* BinaryTree<T>::search(T x)
{
    ....
    return node;
}
```

You put the asterisk in the wrong place ;-)